# C/C++ Multithreaded server/client on Linux crashes

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, networking

I'm a beginner and my task is to write a multi threaded  server/client game for two players in c/c++.

The Problem is, my server crashes after the first client connection.
The client is sending the player name to the server.
The server receives it  and then it crashes.

Error:
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)

Why does it crash ?   My while loop    should accept 2 clients and then jump out from the loop.

I compile the code with

```
 g++ -std=c++17 -o server simple_server_tcp.cpp -lpthread
 g++ -std=c++17 -o client client_tcp.cpp
```

The original game code is written in german but its not realy a part of the question so dont mind it.

This is my first question on stack overflow --> please tell me if i did something wrong.

Here is the server code

```
#include "header_file.h"

int count_on_clients_connections = 0;

void handle(int newsock, char *hello_server); //function for interaction with the client
void recieve_message_from_client(int newsock);
void send_message_to_client_from_server(int newsock);
void player_thread(int client_socket);
void client_thread_player(int client_socket);
void recieve_player_name(int client_sock);

int main(void)
{

   char buffer[1024] = {0};
   char data_sent[256];
   char data_received[256];
   int sock, bytes_send, bytes_received;
   struct addrinfo hints, *res;
   int reuseaddr = 1; /* True */

   //function for testing --> sending message all five seconds;
   void send_message_to_clients_im_still_here(int client_sock_first, int client_sock_second);

   //socket_list_need_for connecting max 2 clients
   int socket_list[2] = {0, 0};

   //all the server thingys
   /* Get the address info */
   memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
   hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
   hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
   if (getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &res) != 0)
   {
      perror("getaddrinfo");
      return 1;
   }

   /* Create the socket */
   sock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
   if (sock == -1)
   {
      perror("socket");
      return 1;
   }

   /* Enable the socket to reuse the address */
   if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseaddr, sizeof(int)) == -1)
   {
      perror("setsockopt");
      return 1;
   }

   /* Bind to the address */
   if (bind(sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1)
   {
      perror("bind");
      return 1;
   }

   /* Listen */
   if (listen(sock, BACKLOG) == -1)
   {
      perror("listen");
      return 1;
   }

   freeaddrinfo(res);
   // all the server thingy end

   cout << "Server is running" << endl
        << "Server is waiting for connection...." << endl
        << endl;

   /* Main loop for connecting new clients  */
   while (1)
   {

      do
      {
         cout << count_on_clients_connections << endl;
         socklen_t size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
         struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
         int player_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &size);
         //hanndling the connection from incoming client and starting it in a thread = player one
         client_thread_player(player_sock);

         cout << "a client connected.." << endl;
         printf("Got a connection from %s on port %d\n", inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr), htons(their_addr.sin_port));
         count_on_clients_connections++;
         cout << count_on_clients_connections << endl;
      } while (count_on_clients_connections <= 2);

      cout << "2 player Connected --> no more connection is allowed" << endl
           << "Now can the game start" << endl;
   }
   close(sock);

   return 0;
}

void recieve_message_from_client(int newsock)

{
   char message_from_client[256];
   message_from_client[256] = recv(newsock, &message_from_client, sizeof(message_from_client), 0);
   cout << message_from_client << endl;
}

void send_message_to_client_from_server(int newsock)
{

   //message send from server
   char hello_server[256] = "Hello from server";
   send(newsock, &hello_server, sizeof(hello_server), 0);
}
//recievieng the name of the player client for the thread function
void recieve_player_name(int client_sock)
{

   char player_name[256];
   player_name[256] = recv(client_sock, &player_name, sizeof(player_name), 0);
   cout << "Player connected: " << player_name << endl;
   cout << "recieve player name was okay" << endl;
}

void player_thread(int client_socket)
{

   //message recieved from client
   char message_from_client[256];
   message_from_client[256] = recv(client_socket, &message_from_client, sizeof(message_from_client), 0);
   cout << "recieve from client was okay " << endl;
   cout << message_from_client << endl;

   send_message_to_client_from_server(client_socket);
   cout << " send was okay " << endl;
   recieve_player_name(client_socket);

   cout << "player thread was finished!" << endl;
}

void client_thread_player(int client_socket)
{

   //sending my client to a thread
   std::thread player_client_thread(player_thread, client_socket);
   //waiting the thread/player to complete his task.
   // kann raus weil keine paralität player_client_one_thread.join();
   //showing the connection
   cout << "client thread player  was okay !!!" << endl;
   player_client_thread.join();
}
//the function handles all the client thingy in a thread


}
```

here is my client

```
#include "header_file.h"

void send_player_name(int sock);
void recieve_function(int sock);

//all the game functions

void board_game(char vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[8][8]);
void column();

//all the game functions ends

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   int sock = 0, bytes_send, bytes_received;
   char data_sent[256];
   char data_received[256];
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
   char buffer[1024] = {0};
   string play_client_name;

   //game_needed_thingys

   //game_needed_thingys_end

   // All the Client socket thingy

   if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
   {
      printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
      return -1;
   }

   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_CLIENT);

   // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
   if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
   {
      printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
      return -1;
   }

   if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
   {
      printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
      return -1;
   }
   // all the client socket thingy _finished

   bool repeat = true;

   while (1)
   {

      //how to send a message to server
      char message_from_client[256] = "Hello from player client";
      send(sock, &message_from_client, sizeof(message_from_client), 0);

      /*How to recieve a  message from server*/
      char message_from_server[256];
      message_from_server[256] = recv(sock, &message_from_server, sizeof(message_from_server), 0);
      cout << message_from_server << endl;

      //Input of a string from console , turned to array and send to server
      send_player_name(sock);

      cout << "end" << endl;

      cout << " wait....." << endl;
      sleep(7);
   }

   //ending connection
   close(sock);
   return (0);
}

//input of a name as string, convert to char array so we can send it to server;
void send_player_name(int sock)
{
   string name;
   cout << "Hi,please tell me the Name of the player ?" << endl;
   cin >> name;
   int n = name.length();
   char char_name[n + 1];
   strcpy(char_name, name.c_str());
   //converting to char array complete
   send(sock, &char_name, sizeof(char_name), 0);
   cout << "Name has been sent " << endl;

   //all the game thingy starts here

   cout << "Its time to start the game for the player " << name << endl;

   char vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[8][8];

   for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) //feels the array vier_gewinnt with 0 chars
      for (int o = 0; o <= 7; o++)
      {
         vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[i][o] = '0';
      }

   board_game(vier_gewinnt_spielfeld);

   cout << "Make your turn !!!" << endl;
}

void recieve_function(int sock)
{

   char message_from_server[256];
   message_from_server[256] = recv(sock, &message_from_server, sizeof(message_from_server), 0);
   usleep(500000);
   cout << message_from_server << endl;
}
```

here is my header

```
#pragma once //header guard so not the same thing is reused !!!

//include server
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* memset() */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h> //usleep

//include the header file where the game is located

using namespace std;

#define PORT "32001" /* Port to listen on */
#define PORT_CLIENT 32001
#define BACKLOG 10 /* Passed to listen() */

//client

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h> //usleep

//all game needed defines
#define RED "\033[31m"    /* Red */
#define BLUE "\033[34m"   /* Blue */
#define YELLOW "\033[33m" /* Yellow */
#define RESET "\033[0m"   /*Reset of the used color*/
#define OVERLINE "\u203e"
#define black_square "\u25A2"

using namespace std;

//include the game file
//#include "vier_gewinnt.cpp"

//double main --> exlude vier_gewinnt ath the moment :D

//game function
void player_name_creation(string &player_1, string &player_2);
void column();
void board_game(char vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[8][8]); //includes column()
int turn_player(string player, char vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[8][8], int &curr_row, int &curr_column);
void unvalid_player_turn(char vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[8][8], int temp, int zeile);
int check_user_input(int Value, char board[8][8]);
int get_row(int curr_column, char Board[8][8]);
int search_four(char gamer, char Grid[8][8]); //winning condition

//server function
void handle(int newsock, char *hello_server); //function for interaction with the client
void recieve_message_from_client(int newsock);
void send_message_to_client_from_server(int newsock);
void player_thread(int client_socket);
void client_thread_player(int client_socket);
void recieve_player_name(int client_sock);

//client_functions
void send_player_name(int sock);
void recieve_function(int sock);

//all the game functions
int search_four(char gamer, char Grid[8][8])
{
    int i, j;

    // Suche waagrecht
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 8 - 3; j++)
            if (Grid[i][j] == gamer && Grid[i][j + 1] == gamer &&
                Grid[i][j + 2] == gamer && Grid[i][j + 3] == gamer)
            {
                //mark_four(i, j, 0, +1);
                return 1;
            }
    // Suche senkrecht
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < 8 - 3; i++)
            if (Grid[i][j] == gamer && Grid[i + 1][j] == gamer &&
                Grid[i + 2][j] == gamer && Grid[i + 3][j] == gamer)
            {
                //mark_four(i, j, +1, 0);
                return 1;
            }
    // Suche diagonal '\'
    for (i = 0; i < 8 - 3; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 8 - 3; j++)
            if (Grid[i][j] == gamer && Grid[i + 1][j + 1] == gamer &&
                Grid[i + 2][j + 2] == gamer && Grid[i + 3][j + 3] == gamer)
            {
                //mark_four(i, j, +1, +1);
                return 1;
            }
    // Suche diagonal '/'
    for (i = 0; i < 8 - 3; i++)
        for (j = 8 - 4; j < 8; j++)
            if (Grid[i][j] == gamer && Grid[i + 1][j - 1] == gamer &&
                Grid[i + 2][j - 2] == gamer && Grid[i + 3][j - 3] == gamer)
            {
                //mark_four(i, j, +1, -1);
                return 1;
            }
    return 0;
}

void player_name_creation(string &player_1, string &player_2) // creates the name of player 1 and player 2
{

    cout << " 4 Gewinnt wird zu 2 geschpielt" << endl;
    cout << "Wie heißt der erste Spieler --> Bitte namen eingeben" << endl;
    cin >> player_1;
    cout << "Wie heißt der zweite Spieler --> Bitte namen eingeben" << endl;
    cin >> player_2;

    cout << "Der Spieler: " << player_1 << RED << " vs" << RESET << " " << player_2 << " den zweiten Spieler: " << endl;
    return;
}

int turn_player(string player, char vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[8][8], int &curr_row, int &curr_column) // Ein Spielerzug mit der rückgabe der spalte
{
    int input_player_column;

    cout << "Der Spieler: " << player << " ist dran" << endl
         << "Bitte waehlen sie die Spalte[1-8] aus, wo sie den Stein reinwerfen wollen" << endl; // text abändern

    //cin >> input_player_column;

    while (!(cin >> input_player_column))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(__INT_MAX__, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input! Try again: ";
    }

    input_player_column--;

    curr_column = check_user_input(input_player_column, vier_gewinnt_spielfeld);
    curr_row = get_row(curr_column, vier_gewinnt_spielfeld);

    while (curr_row == 10)
    {
        cout << "WRONG  --> Ungueltiger Spielerzug --> Die Spalte ist voll --> Waehle eine andere Spalte" << endl;
        turn_player(player, vier_gewinnt_spielfeld, curr_row, curr_column);
    }
}

int check_user_input(int Value, char board[8][8])
{
    while ((Value < 0) || (Value > 7))
    {
        cout << RED << "Falsche eingabe, probieren sie es erneut --> es darf die zahl nur zwischen " << YELLOW << "[1-8]" << RED << " eingegeben werden " << RESET << endl;
        board_game(board);
        cin >> Value;
        Value--;
    }

    return Value;
}

int get_row(int curr_column, char board[8][8])
{
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (board[i][curr_column] == '0')
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return 10; // default value
}

void column()
{
    int reihe_anzeige[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}; //shows column number
    cout << BLUE << "|" << RESET;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) //Gibt die Spalten an
    {

        cout << reihe_anzeige[i] << BLUE << "|" << RESET;
    }

    cout << endl;
    for (int w = 0; w <= 16; w++)
        cout << BLUE << "_" << RESET;

    cout << endl;

    return;
}

void board_game(char vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[8][8]) //creates the board table
{
    column();                    //displays the column of the game board
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) //gibt das spielbrett aus
    {
        cout << BLUE << "|" << RESET;
        for (int o = 0; o <= 7; o++) //colores the output of the array for a  better visual option
        {
            if (vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[i][o] == 'x')
            {
                cout << RED << vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[i][o] << RESET << BLUE << "|" << RESET;
            }
            if (vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[i][o] == '0')
            {
                cout << vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[i][o] << BLUE << "|" << RESET;
            }

            if (vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[i][o] == 'v')
            {
                cout << YELLOW << vier_gewinnt_spielfeld[i][o] << RESET << BLUE << "|" << RESET;
            }

            if (o == 7)
            {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int w = 0; w <= 16; w++) // Gibt den Boden des Spielbrettes aus
        cout << BLUE << OVERLINE << RESET;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Run Log:
Server

```
./server 
Server is running
Server is waiting for connection....

0
client thread player  was okay !!!
recieve from client was okay 
Hello from player client
 send was okay 
Player connected: Klaus
recieve player name was okay
player thread was finished!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Client

```
./client 
Hello from server
Hi,please tell me the Name of the player ?
Klaus
Name has been sent 
Its time to start the game for the player Klaus
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
_________________
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
Make your turn !!!
end
 wait.....
```

Comment: How does it crash? Do you get an error message or a core dump? Please add the console output of the server.

Comment: Please show the full run log. The debug prints would be helpful for anyone looking at the problem.

Comment: i updated my run log

Comment: Any specific reason why there are function definitions in a header?

Comment: No not really, it was my first header file at this moment :D  --> Need to redo this part

Comment: You have, effectively, a join() in the accept loop:(   If you start a thread and then wait for it to terminate, you may as well just call the thread function.....

Answer (score 0):

The same set of errors are repeated throughout the shown code, a typical example:

```
char message_from_client[256];
message_from_client[256] = recv(newsock, &message_from_client,
                                sizeof(message_from_client), 0);
cout << message_from_client << endl;
```

There is no "`message_from_client[256]`". It doesn't exist. `message_from_client` is an array of 256 values, so the valid values are `message_from_client[0]` through `message_from_client[255]`. Assigning something to the 256th, non-existent value results in memory corruption, and is the likely reason for the crash. Modern C++ compilers are actually capable of detecting this common bug. If you received a warning message from your compiler, when compiling the shown code, this would be a lesson never to ignore diagnostic messages from your compiler, even if it still compiles the shown code. Those diagnostic messages are always reported for a reason, and indicate a likely defect and a bug in the compiled code, even if it doesn't violate the formal rules of C++ grammar.

But that's not the only problem. This code obviously assumes that it will always read 256 bytes from the socket. This is not true. Stream sockets don't work this way. Even if the other side of the connection sent 256 bytes, there is no guarantee whatsoever that all 256 bytes will be `recv()`ed. The first call `recv()` might return 1, and calling `recv()` again will read the remaining 255 bytes. That's just an example. Or each time `recv()` gets called, it reads 1 byte, and you must call it repeatedly until the entire message gets received. You cannot make any assumptions like that.

Similarly, when the shown code attempts to send 256 bytes to the socket, the shown code assumes that all 256 bytes were sent. This is not true either:

```
send(sock, &message_from_client, sizeof(message_from_client), 0);
```

This assumes that the entire message gets sent. That is not guaranteed. Both `send()` and `recv()` return the actual number of bytes sent or received, which can be anywhere between 0, and the number of bytes requested, indicating how many bytes were actually sent and received, and you must handle the result, accordingly. If fewer bytes were written than you attempted to write, you must try again and write the remaining, unwritten bytes, until the entire message gets written (assuming that's your intention).

You will have to completely redesign and reimplement your client and server, from scratch, correctly implementing the required rules for reading and writing from/to sockets. It's a lot more work than you appeared to expect, but that's how it must be done.

Comment: send(sock, &message_from_client, sizeof(message_from_client), 0); the ampersand is not needed: &message_from_client is the address of where the array is stored: it should be send(sock, message_from_client, sizeof(message_from_client), 0);

Comment: First, thank you for the feedback.  I have a struggle with the communication between the server and client. It is the first time that I'm writing something like that. I thought i have to define a buffer which can be sent between server and client.  I will try to redo this again.  I'm really thankful for examples

Comment: In `var = recv(...)` the type of `var` must be ssize_t, not char.  For examples, see https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/